# Threading in ASP.NET and the request thread pool

Tags: asp.net, async-await

Supposedly .NET Framework maintains a pool of threads (default for .NET 4.5 is 5,000) that are used to service ASP.NET requests. It is said that large applications with high concurrency of long-running requests could lead to a condition called thread starvation. Therefore, one should make asynchronous requests for high latency calls to free up request threads.

But doesn't the asynchronous request spawn another thread from the thread pool anyway to complete its work? Does the new thread come from a pool different from the request thread pool and is there a limit to how many of these threads can be created?

Comment: Do you have some reference to give, some examples, some blog, something from real life ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But doesn't the asynchronous request spawn another thread from the thread pool anyway to complete its work?

Yes, but only after the asynchronous work has been completed. While the work is being done (which usually means waiting for disk or network), asynchronous code doesn't block a thread.

> Does the new thread come from a pool different from the request thread pool and is there a limit to how many of these threads can be created?

There is no separate thread pool for ASP.NET. Asynchronous code and ASP.NET use the same thread pool, which means they also share the same limit.

And the limit on threads is not the only issue (if it was, you could just call [`ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx) to increase it). The other issues are that each thread uses 1 MB of memory, which is especially problematic for 32-bit applications. Also, having too many threads executing at the same time is inefficient, because of context switching.

Comment: can you elaborate on "Yes, but only after the asynchronous work has been completed"? What if I used this contrived example as an asynchronous method: 
Thread.Sleep(5000); int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId; Based on what you're saying, would threadId be null because this async method has not completed yet?

Comment: @jodev No, but that's not a truly asynchronous method. Your method would block a thread for the whole 5 seconds. If you instead used `await Task.Delay(5000);  int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;`, then for those 5 seconds, no thread would be used by that method. But the following line would execute on some thread, `ManagedThreadId` can never return `null`, or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks, making more sense.

Comment: A great article explaining how async tasks do *not* necessarily use a background thread can be found here: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html